# How can I put a number in html that will increase by 1 every day automatically?

Tags: html

Similar to "This site has been accident-free for x days," the number would increase automatically every day. I'm ok with entering a starting number or the date from which I want to count. Also like a reverse countdown. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome, have you looked for a way to do it already?

Comment: That's not how that works.

Comment: You can't do this in HTML alone. You can do it on the server using your choice of server programming language, or you can do it in the browser with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the start date and minus it from the current date, then get the difference.

Using JavaScript

```js
const date1 = new Date('11/18/2021');
const date2 = new Date();
const diffTime = Math.abs(date2 - date1);
const diffDays = Math.round(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
document.getElementById('x').innerHTML = diffDays;
```

```html
<div>This site has been accident-free for <span id="x"></span>day(s)
```

Comment: This doesn't provide an adequate solution to the question.

Comment: What do I need to change or add (other than the date for date1) if I wanted to copy this into my html file?

Comment: date1 is the start date. You want to run it dynamically?

Comment: The beginning date would be 5/15/21 and I want it to increase automatically every day. I'm just using the Notepad program in Windows and saving as an html file.

Comment: const date1 = new Date('5/15/2021');
const date2 = new Date(); // will pick the current date; Each day added minus date1 will give you the difference.

Comment: Hey Kingsley, sorry I think I'm missing something in front of const date1. That actual code is showing up on my webpage after putting it in my html file. If it's not too much trouble could you show me the code that could be pasted into my Notepad html file? Also is there something that needs to go between "<span id="x"></span>"? Nothing shows up.

Comment: The <span id="x"></span> will be taken care of by the javascript. This is how you will write it:
https://codepen.io/ezehkingsleyuchenna/pen/NWvJebE

<body>
<div>This site has been accident-free for <span id="x"></span>day(s)
<script>
const date1 = new Date('11/18/2021');
const date2 = new Date();
const diffTime = Math.abs(date2 - date1);
const diffDays = Math.round(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
document.getElementById('x').innerHTML = diffDays;
</script>
</body>

Thick this as the answer if this code helped you. Thank You

Comment: That works! I think I needed to have it within the <body></body> tags. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome, don't forget to thick my answer as the answer.

Comment: Actually it's because the const date code needed to be within <script></script> tags and the "<div>This site has been accident-free for <span id="x"></span>day(s)" needs to be ahead of it all. Hopefully that helps anyone else looking for a solution to this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```js
function getAccidentFreeDays() {
    const dateThen = new Date('11/17/2021'); // enter the accident free day
    const dateNow = new Date(); // gets todays date

    const diff = dateThen.getTime() - dateNow.getTime(); // get the difference between the date then and the date now

    const days = Math.ceil(diff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); // converts the milliseconds to days
    return days;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var tik = 0; tik < 1e7; tik++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}

var counter = 0;
while (true) {
  sleep(86400000);
  counter++;
}
```

```css
/* Whatever you have here */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <!-- whatever you have here -->
  <body>
    <!-- whatever you have here -->
    <script src="/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I found a good way to add sleeping (a.k.a waiting) into JS and then converted days to milliseconds (quite a lot to do), so you can insert sleep with the milliseconds from a day, and then add counter. You can then insert counter into your tag represented with x.

Comment: Hey Alvin, I'm pretty new to this. What data needs to be added to your post to make it work? Just for an example can you include "This site has been accident free for 30 days" where the number would increase every day?

Comment: The number would be increased at the `counter++` in the code. You might need to add a `document.getElementById('x').innerText = counter` but I didn't add that since I did not know your id (or even if you have it).

Comment: All I'm doing is making simple websites for personal use with the Notepad program. I was hoping for something I can just copy straight into my html file that will work.

Comment: Try this: `<script>function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var tik = 0; tik < 1e7; tik++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}

var counter = 0;
while (true) {
  sleep(86400000);
  counter++;
  document.getElementById('x').innerText = counter;
}</script>`

Comment: Note you will need to add line spacing yourself; it did not parse.

Comment: I copied that into my html file and nothing showed up on the webpage. I added the start date in "new Date(05/15/2021)" and that didn't do anything either. It's probably something obvious I'm missing but I can't figure it out. What needs to be added to the most recent code you provided?

Comment: Try this for the js; the`while` loop will not finish:
JS:
`function getDaysSince(day) {
    var beg = new Date(day).getTime();
    var tdy = new Date().getTime;
    document.getElementById('x').innerText = Math.abs(beg - tdy);
}`

HTML:
`<html>
    <!-- what you have here -->
    <body>
        <!-- what you have here -->
        <p>This site has been accident-free for <span id='x'>0</span> days</p>
        <script>// The script</script>
    </body>
</html>`